# ASP.NET Core adding Area to form post without specifying

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

So the problems stands like this, I have a top navbar which has a logout link like this

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                @if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
                {
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <form method="post" asp-controller="account" asp-action="logout">
                            <button type="submit" style="width:auto"
                                    class="nav-link btn btn-link py-0">
                                Logout @User.Identity.Name
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                }

                else
                {
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="account" asp-action="register"> Register</a>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
```

My project also includes areas so I have 2 areas Broker/Customer :

[image]

After login with a broker the form action for logout will modify to this

[image]

action: /Broker/account/logout, this will cause a problem because i don't have that controller in my Broker area

The question: why it is not showing a /account/logout action like it is stated in my form "post" code:
form method="post" asp-controller="account" asp-action="logout"

Account Controller is not defined in any area, it belongs to default Controllers folder as you can see on the image and that AccountController / Logout action will just redirect to HomeController / Index action.

Please help me understand :D

EDIT: MY ROUTING :

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
               name: "default",
               pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
```

Comment: 1) What is your route config ?
2) Do you have a tag [Area("Broker")] in your AccountController ?
3) What is your redirect code ? 
4) Do you have any controller defined in your areas ?

Comment: 2) Do you have a tag [Area("Broker")] in your AccountController ? = "Broker" Tag is present in Broker/HomeController, that AccountController is separate, it does not belong to any area       3) What is your redirect code ? : don't have anything defined  4) Do you have any controller defined in your areas ?  yes, there is Broker/Controllers/HomeController Updated post with my routing

Comment: First problem I see is that you can't have 2 routes defined with the same name.
Does it matter with an uppercase ?  asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout" asp-area=""

Comment: Because you did not define asp-area in your form tag, it will maybe take the one found in your current route (and because you are on /broker, a default area will be selected). Try to set an empty asp-area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation :

- You logged in on /broker/home so you route is /broker/home/index
- You then render the menu without specifying a default area (then it is set by default to "broker" when evaluating the tags).
- The broker area **exists** so your first route is matched.

So you have the solution to set the asp-area to empty string in your form tag
(because the menu can be rendered in an existing area or not)

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution, in my AccountController, which does not belong to any area, just use route attribute [Route("/Account/Logout")], in this way the form post action is generated correctly [image]

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("/Account/Logout")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("login", "account");
    }
```

So html stays untouched

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                @if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
                {
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <form method="post" asp-controller="account" asp-action="logout">
                            <button type="submit" style="width:auto"
                                    class="nav-link btn btn-link py-0">
                                Logout @User.Identity.Name
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                }

                else
                {
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="account" asp-action="register"> Register</a>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Maybe consider to set the [Route("/Account")] on the controller scope and then overriding the route on the method scope if necessary to avoid some duplication !